# MYSQL Database Design - Source of Income different table - Is there better way than polymorphism

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

The scenario is a user should input his/her source of income whether business, employed or retired.
The data below is my current database table. Is there a better way to handle the scenario without using polymorphism?

```
user table
sourceOfIncome_type
sourceOfIncome_id

sourceOfincome_business table
 - companyName
 - monthlyIncome
sourceOfincome_employed table
 - companyName
 - position
sourceOfincome_retired table
 - retiredSince
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use Single table inheritance, where all source of incomes are defined in a single table but your code treats them as separate models.
This way your user model only has the income id to reference its source of income, and you can leverage foreign keys checks and cascade.
I don’t think TypeORM supports it by default, you can check how MikroORM implements it
https://mikro-orm.io/docs/inheritance-mapping#single-table-inheritance